# windows 7: Name resolution not working as expected when connected via VPN

Tags: windows-7, domain-name-system

I have a local machine on my home network called "sheeva" (it's a sheevaplug linux server running subversion).

I can connect to it fine using it's local IP address of 192.168.1.108, and when I'm not connected to the VPN I can connect to it using the machine name "sheeva".

When I am connected to the office using VPN the name "sheeva" is being mapped to a totally different IP address. I can still connect to it fine using its IP address.

When I run nslookup "sheeva", I get two responses that are both different IP addresses than my local sheeva plug's IP address.

Is there a way to force Windows 7 to search for local machine names first? If so, would this solution make name resolution run significantly slower?

Comment: Do your VPN's DNS servers forward to resolvers that do `NXDOMAIN` hijacking, such as OpenDNS?  And how is it resolving locally - via DNS from a local server, or something else like WINS or mDNS?

Answer (score 0):

Check your interface binding and make sure your vpn interface is the first one. 
here's how to do it : http://techrena.net/view-change-network-adapter-card-priority-binding-order-windows-7/